# NSTextView's deleteToBeginningOfLine: deletes the whole string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTextView that contains multiline text. When calling `-deleteToBeginningOfLine:`, the whole string is deleted, instead of the last line:

```c
NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

textView.string = @"foo\nbar";
[textView deleteToBeginningOfLine:nil];
NSAssert([textView.string isEqualToString:@"foo\n"], @""); // fail, string is "".

// Modifying the selected range doesn't help.
textView.string = @"foo\nbar";
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.string.length, 0);
[textView deleteToBeginningOfLine:nil];
NSAssert([textView.string isEqualToString:@"foo\n"], @""); // ditto.

// Using \r\n changes nothing.
textView.string = @"foo\r\nbar";
[textView deleteToBeginningOfLine:nil];
NSAssert([textView.string isEqualToString:@"foo\r\n"], @""); // ditto.
```

Once the view has been laid out in a window, it works as expected. But I'd like to edit the string before adding the view to any other view. How do I make this work?

Comment: Are you really sure that you understood the term "line"? I'm pretty sure, that you did not. It is not "paragraph".

Comment: @Amin I thought a line is a portion of of a string separated by single newline, so string "foo\nbar" consists of two lines, "foo" and "bar". Deleting beginning to line (from somewhere) should delete one line at most, and not two lines. So what do you mean by "paragraph" then? Isn't it a set of "line"s separated by two or more continuous newlines?

Comment: Then I found "line" actually counts a newline inserted as a result of text wrapping. When the text view is too narrow "foo\nbar" can be more than two lines.

Comment: Parts of a string separated by '\n' are paragraphs (in our days). "Line" is a term of type setting: It is not separated by '\n', but is created by the fact that a paragraph could not be laid out in a single line. A line is a phenomena of layout, a phenomena on screen.

Comment: When you look to the texts on SO, you will recognize that they are divided into paragraphs, one for each [enter] you pressed. 

One \n -> many lines. 

If you look to the source code on SO, every paragraph (enter) is a single line. This is the reason for what you have to scroll horizontally. 

One \n -> one line == one paragraph. 

The source code paragraphs are not wrapped. So, what you are looking for are paragraphs, not lines (in text views terms).

Answer (score 0):

Create text view with good size of frame.

```c
NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
textView.string = @"foo\nbar";
[textView deleteToBeginningOfLine:nil];
NSAssert([textView.string isEqualToString:@"foo\n"], @""); // ok.

// Don't make the frame too small.
NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1, 1)];
textView.string = @"foo\nbar";
[textView deleteToBeginningOfLine:nil];
NSAssert([textView.string isEqualToString:@"foo\n"], @""); // fail, string is "foo\nba".
```